# Add new methods to a resource controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know if it is possible to add new methods to a resource controller in Laravel and how you do it.

I know that these methods are the default (index, create, store, edit, update, destroy). Now I want to add additional methods and routes to the same controller.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 332, accepted):

Just add a route to that method separately, **before** you register the resource:

```php
Route::get('foo/bar', 'FooController@bar');
Route::resource('foo', 'FooController');
```

Comment: Note that your new methods have to go *above* the `::resource` otherwise you get an error message, "No query results for model".

Comment: How would you pass a parameter like {id}?  Currently I've coded my custom method inline in routes.php (like the example here  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters).  Ideally I'd like to pass the parameter to run in FooController.

Comment: Found the problem - wasn't in the Route syntax.  Was actually in some custom Middleware that I'm using!  Route::get('foo/{id}/bar', 'FooController@bar');  will pass the id to bar($id) method.  Thanks!

Comment: Can someone explain why the custom route should go above the resource route ??? I've done some tests and seems to have no diference between putting above or below...

Comment: @RicardoVigatti - The resource registers this route: `Route::get('foo/{id}', ...)`. This swallows all routes starting with `foo` and having one additional segments, including `foo/bar`.

Comment: @Joseph Silber Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594340/how-can-i-implement-resource-controllers-if-i-use-many-get-on-the-laravel

Comment: Any way to add N number of method separately. Do i need to add each method separately in routes?

Comment: Much appreciated. I had the extra route AFTER the resource routes, and I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 40):

Yeah, It's possible..

In my case I add method : data to handle request for /data.json in HTTP POST method.

This what I did.

First we extends **Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar** to add new method **data**

```php
<?php

namespace App\MyCustom\Routing;

use Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar as OriginalRegistrar;

class ResourceRegistrar extends OriginalRegistrar
{
    // add data to the array
    /**
     * The default actions for a resourceful controller.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $resourceDefaults = ['index', 'create', 'store', 'show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy', 'data'];


    /**
     * Add the data method for a resourceful route.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  string  $base
     * @param  string  $controller
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
     */
    protected function addResourceData($name, $base, $controller, $options)
    {
        $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name).'/data.json';

        $action = $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'data', $options);

        return $this->router->post($uri, $action);
    }
}
```

After that, make your new **ServiceProvider** or use **AppServiceProvider** instead.

In method **boot**, add this code :

```php
    public function boot()
    {
        $registrar = new \App\MyCustom\Routing\ResourceRegistrar($this->app['router']);

        $this->app->bind('Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar', function () use ($registrar) {
            return $registrar;
        });
    }
```

then :

add to your route :

```php
Route::resource('test', 'TestController');
```

Check by `php artisan route:list` 
And you will find new method **'data'**

Comment: Your solution works for me.. Can you tell me if you discovered any issue after some months using this code?

Comment: Thanks @RicardoVigatti.
I used this since laravel 5.2 and now I use this in my recent project with L5.3 and have no issue with it. 
Let me know if you have one, may be I can help you..

Comment: nice, i'm implementing this in my 5.0 project. The solution seems very consistent, but, if any issue come to pass, it will be after some weeks.

Comment: @MokhamadRofi'udin I've implemented your solution, the new route is added to the route list but it seems that the corresponding method is not added. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Siavosh just write your method in controller 
i.e. I add method data() :
`    public function data(Request $request)
{
}`

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Awesome, the solution that I need in the most of my projects.

Comment: Why this doesnt work in `::apiResource` ?

Answer (score 35):

I just did that, to add a GET "delete" method.

After creating your files, you just need to add

```
'AntonioRibeiro\Routing\ExtendedRouterServiceProvider',
```

to 'providers' in your app/config.php

Edit the Route alias in this same file:

```
'Route'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
```

changing it to

```
'Route'           => 'AntonioRibeiro\Facades\ExtendedRouteFacade',
```

And make sure those files are being autoloaded, they must be in some directory that you have in your composer.json ("autoload" section).

Then you just need to:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

And this (look at the last line) is the result if you run `php artisan routes`:

[image: routes list]
Those are my source files:

**ExtendedRouteFacade.pas**

```
<?php namespace AntonioRibeiro\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade as IlluminateFacade;

class ExtendedRouteFacade extends IlluminateFacade {

    /**
     * Determine if the current route matches a given name.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function is($name)
    {
        return static::$app['router']->currentRouteNamed($name);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the current route uses a given controller action.
     *
     * @param  string  $action
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function uses($action)
    {
        return static::$app['router']->currentRouteUses($action);
    }

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'router'; }

}
```

**ExtendedRouter.pas**

```
<?php namespace AntonioRibeiro\Routing;

class ExtendedRouter extends \Illuminate\Routing\Router {

    protected $resourceDefaults = array('index', 'create', 'store', 'show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy', 'delete');

    /**
     * Add the show method for a resourceful route.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  string  $base
     * @param  string  $controller
     * @return void
     */
    protected function addResourceDelete($name, $base, $controller)
    {
        $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name).'/{'.$base.'}/destroy';

        return $this->get($uri, $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'delete'));
    }

}
```

**ExtendedRouteServiceProvider.pas**

```
<?php namespace AntonioRibeiro\Routing;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ExtendedRouterServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['router'] = $this->app->share(function() { return new ExtendedRouter($this->app); });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return array('router');
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the same for Laravel 5 and Above? I have been trying to reproduce this... But I can't seem to find where they are registering the 'route' Accessor in the container.

Comment: why the file has the extension .pas?

Comment: Make sense but provider part seems to not work with laravel 8.0.

Comment: Overcomplicated sadly

Answer (score 16):

```
Route::resource('foo', 'FooController');
Route::controller('foo', 'FooController');
```

Give this a try .Put you extra methods like getData() etc etc .. This worked for me to keep route.php clean

Comment: Yas this works . Laravel 5.1 Documentation did't mention that Route::resource and Route::controller can be used together rather they mentioned about Supplementing Resource Controllers. So this is confused. But your ans proved that these are can be used together

Comment: I am sorry Hassan jamal, these two are not working together. So now how can I set a custom post method in a controller if I use only Route::resource

Answer (score 3):

Using Laravel >5 
Find the web.php file in routes folder add your methods

You can use route::resource to route all these methods index, show, store, update, destroy in your controller in one line

```
Route::get('foo/bar', 'NameController@bar');
Route::resource('foo', 'NameController');
```

Answer (score 3):

Previously I defined my route as:

```
Route::get('foo/bar', 'FooController@bar');
Route::resource('foo', 'FooController');
```

It gave the error:

> route foo.bar is not defined

And then after some Googling I added name

```
Route::get('foo/bar', 'FooController@bar')->name('foo.bar');
```

And it worked fine.

Comment: It works. In recent version of Laravel (e.g - 10.x) you can do this - 
`Route::get('foo/bar', [FooController::class, 'bar'])->name('foo.bar');`

Answer (score 2):

I solve by

Create a custom router file that extends the `BaseRouter`

```
// src/app/Custom/Router.php


<?php

namespace App\Custom;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router as BaseRouter;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Router extends BaseRouter
{
    public function customResource($name, $controller, array $options = [])
    {
        $model = Str::singular($name); // this is optional, i need it for Route Model Binding

        $this
            ->get( // set the http methods
                $name .'/{' . $model . '}/audit',
                $controller . '@audit'
            )->name($name . '.audit');

        return $this->resource($name, $controller, $options);
    }
}
```

Then register at `src/bootstrap/app.php`

```
$app->singleton('router', function ($app) {
    return new \App\Custom\Router($app['events'], $app);
});
```

And use it on /routes/web.php

```
Route::customResource(
    'entries',
    'EntryController'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new method and a route to that method.

In your controller:

```
public function foo($bar=“default”)
{
      //do stuff
}
```

And in your web routes

```
Route::get(“foo/{$bar}”, “MyController@foo”);
```

Just be sure the method in the controller is public.

Answer (score 1):

As of Laravel 9 this appears to have been made much simpler. The following works fine, even if you add the new method after the Resource controller was created.

```
Route::get('/foo/bar', [FooController::class, 'bar']);

Route::resource('/foo', FooController::class);
```

Just be sure to include the new method on top, as the remaining /foo/[any] namespace will be reserved for the Resource controller on that line. As is the convention for Laravel routes.

Comment: Also the order of the lines matter

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Laravel, but as of Laravel 10, I was able to group resource and custom route all together like that. And you can add as many custom route as you would like into that group.

```
Route::controller(FooController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::resource('foos', FooController::class);
    // The route to add
    Route::get('yourroute/{foo}', 'test')->name('foos.test');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

If you run artisan route:list you can validate it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your [macros](https://www.larashout.com/laravel-macros-extending-laravels-core-classes#:%7E:text=to%20define%20macros.-,What%20is%20Laravel%20Macro%3F,a%20PHP%20trait%20called%20Macroable.), in my case it looks like this.

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;

Router::macro('crudResource', function ($name, $controller, array $options = []) {
    $only = ['index', 'show', 'store', 'update', 'destroy', 'restore'];

    if (isset($options['except'])) {
        $only = array_diff($only, (array)$options['except']);
    }

    if (in_array('restore', $only)) {
        $this->put($name . '/restore/{' . ($model = Str::singular($name)) . '}', [$controller, 'restore'])
            ->name($name . '.restore')
            ->can('delete', $model)
            ->withTrashed();
    }

    return $this->resource($name, $controller, array_merge([
                                                               'only' => $only,
                                                           ], $options))
        ->withTrashed(['index', 'show']);
});
```

### Route

```
Route::crudResource('initial_balance_banks', InitialBalanceBankController::class);
Route::crudResource('bank_movements', BankMovementController::class)->except('restore');
Route::crudResource('outcoming_bank_orders', OutcomingBankOrderController::class, ['except' => ['restore']]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just add a new method called (files) and works !!!

**Route::get('sections/{section}/files', [SectionController::class,'files'])->name('sections.files');
Route::resource('sections',SectionController::class)->names('sections');**

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -3):

This works pretty good too. No need to add more routes just use show method of the resource controller like this :

```
public function show($name){

 switch ($name){
   case 'foo':
    $this -> foo();
    break;
   case 'bar':
    $this ->bar();
    break; 
  defautlt:
    abort(404,'bad request');
    break;
 }

}
public function foo(){}
publcc function bar(){}
```

I use the default to throw custom error page.

Comment: This feels like a real code smell. I wouldnt want my controllers handling multiple actions.

Comment: Isn't this breaking the REST concept?

Comment: There is no need to do such thing!!! That's why we have routes in the first place. The routing logic can not be placed on the controllers.