# Uploading files to a resource controller (RESTful API)

Tags: api, rest, url, laravel, restful-url

I'm developing a RESTful API with Laravel 4 in which I want to upload pictures related to users (profile pics or galleries). I want to keep it as REST orthodox as I can.
How should I treat the pictures? as a separate resource (relation)? And what would be the best way to map them in my URLs and actions?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option I found was using Laravel's nested resources. Here's a quick and effective tut by Jeffrey Way on how to achieve this.
http://tutsplus.com/lesson/nested-resources

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use one controller across the whole application dedicated to uploading files you can treat that as a  resource.

The `resource` supported actions in Laravel are the folling:

http://paste.laravel.com/Qs6

If you instead want to add an additional action and URL besides the default, you can achieve that by doing this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16661375/385402

Comment: Using Laravel's supported actions, how would I be able to make the relation between the file and the user? And if I declare a new action, how could I make the relation while still respecting REST?
@glad-to-help

Comment: I am not sure which aspect of REST would be violated. Could you please specify?