# Laravel Route::controller with additional parameters

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to figure out whether there is a way of adding url parameters to the Route::controller call.

What I have at the moment for my control panel is:

```
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => 'admin',
        'namespace' => 'Admin'
    ],
    function() {

        Route::group(
            [
                'prefix' => '',
                'before' => 'auth.admin'
            ],
            function() {

                Route::controller('page', 'PageController');

                Route::controller('article', 'ArticleController');

            }

        );

        Route::controller('/', 'LoginController');

    }
);
```

Now - each of the controllers will have the post / getEdit actions, which will require the url `id` parameter to be passed over in the simple format of `/admin/page/edit/{id}`.

My question is - is there a way to perhaps add some parameters to the Route::controller method or do I have to do them all using `Route::get` / `Route::post` approach?

I know I can do it by adding two extra cases with `get` and `post` above the given controller call:

```
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => 'admin',
        'namespace' => 'Admin'
    ],
    function() {

        Route::group(
            [
                'prefix' => '',
                'before' => 'auth.admin'
            ],
            function() {

                Route::get('page/edit/{id}', 'PageController@getEdit');
                Route::post('page/edit/{id}', 'PageController@postEdit');

                Route::controller('page', 'PageController');

                Route::controller('article', 'ArticleController');

            }

        );

        Route::controller('/', 'LoginController');

    }
);
```

but perhaps there's a better approach?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Route::resource`:

```
Route::resource('resource', 'ResourceController');
```

This will register the following routes:

```
GET       /resource                 index   resource.index
GET       /resource/create          create  resource.create
POST      /resource                 store   resource.store
GET       /resource/{resource}      show    resource.show
GET       /resource/{resource}/edit edit    resource.edit
PUT/PATCH /resource/{resource}      update  resource.update
DELETE    /resource/{resource}      destroy resource.destroy
```

You can use it together with `only` or `except` to choose what routes to be included (or excluded):

```
Route::resource('resource', 'ResourceController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'update', 'destroy']]);
```

Read more about restful resource controllers in the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

This post might also be interesting: [Laravel 4 - Route::resource vs Route::controller. Which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102534/laravel-4-routeresource-vs-routecontroller-which-to-use)

Comment: So I take - `resource` would be used to pass the `id` of the given record. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `{resource}` is the identifier for the record and is passed to the controller.