# Laravel resource group destroy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

When we use resource route, we have the URL to be something like this for doing deletion.

```
DELETE http://localhost/user/1
```

How can we do deletion for more than one id in a single request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to [create your own route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661292/add-new-methods-to-a-resource-controller-in-laravel-4/16661375#16661375) for that:

```
Route::delete('users', 'UsersController@deleteMany');
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Then you can send a DELETE request with the ids in the body:

```
DELETE /users

[1,2,3,4]
```

Then use that in your controller:

```
public function deleteMany()
{
    User::whereIn('id', Request::json()->all())->delete();
}
```