# How do I override laravel resource route default method?

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I have this schema for my REST API urls:

```
Verb    Url                         Method

GET     /tasks                      findAll   
GET     /tasks/{id}                 findOne    
POST    /tasks                      create   
PUT     /tasks/{id}                 update    
DELETE  /tasks/{id}                 deleteOne
DELETE  /tasks                      deleteAll
```

Is there a way for override the default method of Route Resource Laravel built-in methods (store,create,edit etc...) and create with a single line my custom route associated with my controller?

For example:

```
Route::resource('/tasks', 'TasksController');
```

Instead of:

```
Route::get('/tasks', 'TasksController@findAll');
Route::get('/tasks/{id}', 'TasksController@findOne');
Route::post('/tasks', 'TasksController@create');
Route::put('/tasks/{id}', 'TasksController@update');
Route::delete('/tasks', 'TasksController@deleteAll');
Route::delete('/tasks/{id}', 'TasksController@deleteOne');
```

Comment: You can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661292/add-new-methods-to-a-resource-controller-in-laravel).

Comment: Thanks but this is for add additional route actions without override default methods.

Comment: Sorry you had to scroll down to a certain [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36170234/1780996). For every new method you make a method like `addResourceData()` and add the methods in `protected $resourceDefaults = [....]`. Also remove unwanted in `$resourceDefaults`.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen good this seems that I want, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved making these steps changing the ResourceRegistrar.php class, this achieve my request. (suggest by @Thomas Van der Veen):

1) I have replaced $resourceDefaults array with my desires methods:

```
protected $resourceDefaults = ['findAll', 'findOne', 'create', 'update', 'deleteOne', 'deleteAll'];
```

2) After I have create the methods which execute the actions, deleting the olders.

```
    protected function addResourceFindAll($name, $base, $controller, $options)
{
    $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name);

    $action = $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'findAll', $options);

    return $this->router->get($uri, $action);
}

protected function addResourceFindOne($name, $base, $controller, $options)
{
    $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name).'/{'.$base.'}';

    $action = $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'findOne', $options);

    return $this->router->get($uri, $action);
}

protected function addResourceCreate($name, $base, $controller, $options)
{
    $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name);

    $action = $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'create', $options);

    return $this->router->post($uri, $action);
}

protected function addResourceUpdate($name, $base, $controller, $options)
{
    $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name).'/{'.$base.'}';

    $action = $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'update', $options);

    return $this->router->put($uri, $action);
}

protected function addResourceDeleteAll($name, $base, $controller, $options)
{
    $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name);

    $action = $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'deleteAll', $options);

    return $this->router->delete($uri, $action);
}

protected function addResourceDeleteOne($name, $base, $controller, $options)
{
    $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name).'/{'.$base.'}';

    $action = $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'deleteOne', $options);

    return $this->router->delete($uri, $action);
}
```

That's it, works very well!

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been looking for this information for a while, but I have a doubt if modifying this part of the kernel may carry some additional risk or simply does not affect the security of the web, in my case I am only going to add a new one to post with datatables.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Laravel documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers

About deleteAll action, Laravel doesn't provide a default call for that. 
I would recommend to avoid this.

In order to create a resource controller just type on your terminal this command:

```
php artisan make:controller TasksController --resource
```

This will create a controller with default CRUD actions you'll have to fill.

Then in routes.php just add:

```
Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController');
```

You'll be able to send calls to server like you described.

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. The Laravel default actions contains actions which I don't need (show and edit for example). I have solved overriding ResourceRegistrar.php class for change and delete unnecessary laravel actions.