# How do I override a laravel resource route?

Tags: laravel-5.6

I don't think this post [How do I override laravel resource route default method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407032/how-do-i-override-laravel-resource-route-default-method) solves my problem.

Normal resource route is that "index" shows all items. What I want to do is have "index" show all ***related*** items for a particular id.

So when I select a classroom from the list, I want the index action that I'm calling, to show, as it's index function, all the people for that specific classroom.

So I replaced the default resource route

```
//Route::resources(['attendees' => 'attendeesController']);
```

with

```
Route::resource('attendees', 'attendeesController')->names([
    'index'   => 'attendees.index',
    'store'   => 'attendees.store',
    'create'  => 'attendees.create',
    'show'    => 'attendees.evaluation',
    'update'  => 'attendees.update',
    'destroy' => 'attendees.destroy',
    'edit'    => 'attendees.edit',
]);
```

So in my controller, I have this:

```
public function index(Request $request,$id)
{
    dd($request);
    ...
}
```

And in my view of classrooms, on a particular classroom id I have this

```
<a href="{{route('attendees.index', ['classroom' => $data->id])}}">{{$data->Reference}}
```

- As far as I can see, I'm passing the parameter to the controller.
- And the controller is setup to expect a $id parameter

So why am I getting this? I'm guessing something pretty basic, but I can't see what.

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function
App\Http\Controllers\AttendeesController::index(), 
1 passed and exactly 2 expected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default index action is expecting an`$id` so you can set that to null

```
public function index(Request $request,$id = null)
```

Also, if you want to fetch related items for a particular `$id` according to the docs URL would be `attendees/123` which will be redirected to `show` function. So you need to edit that route as well. Instead of that try passing a query param to index route and using the query param you can get the related data. 
instead of 
`attendees/123` it will be `attendees?id=123`

Query param is set to display the related items, else display the indexes.
if you still want to achieve it via index you need to change the routes as below

```
Route::resource('attendees', 'AttendeesController',['only' => ['index', 'create', 'store']]);

Route::get('/attendees/{id}', 'AttendeesController@index');
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me,  the difference between `attendees/123` and `attendees?id=123`

Comment: follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552248/when-to-use-queryparam-vs-pathparam#answer-11569077

Comment: Since you need to display related items of a particular ID(kind of filtering), using query param suits well.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have passed in only 1 parameter. The method "index" in the controller is expecting 2 parameters. You might want to check your route.php file.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing