# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar::addResourceEmployee()

Tags: laravel, routes

I have this route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::resource('admin', 'EmployeeController');
```

I have model Employee and EmployeeController( with empty resource methods)

```
Error : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar::addResourceEmployee()
```

What is wrong with my code? I have used the same approach in other project and it worked.

Comment: This error came on which route????

Comment: in all routes, when i delete resource route it works @ManishYadav

Comment: did you created the controller using the `artisan` command or manually

Comment: yes, php artisan make:migration EmployeeController --resource @ManishYadav

Comment: it's `php artisan make:controller` not `make:migration`. make migration is used to create database migrations. Use this command `php artisan make:controller EmployeeController --resource` to create your controller

Comment: i have  created  controller as  **php artisan make:controller EmployeeController --resource**   i made mistake previous comment / all have been already created and problem is resource not working @ManishYadav

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource('admin', 'EmployeeController');
```

is attempting to bind to a model named Admin.

```
Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeeController');
```

should work with the model you have. To make it work with `admin`, name the resource parameter.

```
Route::resource('admin', 'EmployeeController', ['parameters' => [
    'admin' => 'employee'
]]);
```

**edit**

Did you reference something outside the Laravel docs to use `AddResourceEmployee()`. Seems like a custom solution to me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16661564/320487

Comment: Where is `addResourceEmployee()` being defined? Did you extend the `Router` class? The reference I've found is others extending the class to add those static methods themselves. See: http://techqa.info/programming/question/16661292/add-new-methods-to-a-resource-controller-in-laravel