# Add many new default routes to Route::resource in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to add some default routes for the whole model, since my models all use these methods, is there a way to do this?
Specifically the methods: trash(), restore(), forceDelete(), removeAll(), restoreAll(), forceDeleteAll();

`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Article;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){}

    public function create(){}

    public function store(ArticleRequest $request){}

    public function update(ArticleRequest $request, $id){}

    public function destroy($id){}

    public function trash(){}

    public function restore($id){}

    public function forceDelete($id)v

    public function removeAll(Request $request){}

    public function restoreAll(Request $request){}

    public function forceDeleteAll(Request $request){}

}
```

`

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add new methods to a resource controller in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661292/add-new-methods-to-a-resource-controller-in-laravel)

Comment: do you want more default routes defined for `Route::resource`?

Comment: The Stubs are in the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Console/stubs`. It is not advised to change these as they will get overwritten by updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the stubs that are used when using artisan make commands by executing the `artisan stub:publish` command. Then customise the controller stub in `stubs/controller.stub` (or any other stub) to your needs.

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#stub-customization

Comment: This only makes the method available when I create the controller using the command line, but I still have to declare the Route, is there a way to make my route default for those methods as well, when using Route::resource ?